# How to access elements from a 1-D array using nested loops?

Tags: javascript, arrays, for-loop, multidimensional-array

I need to store the following data in a vector **(in this order)**:

```js
cAge[0]  = 'Age (1) (1)';
cAge[1]  = 'Age (1) (2)';
cAge[2]  = 'Age (1) (3)';
cAge[3]  = 'Age (2) (1)';
cAge[4]  = 'Age (2) (2)';
cAge[5]  = 'Age (2) (3)';
cAge[6]  = 'Age (3) (1)';
cAge[7]  = 'Age (3) (2)';
cAge[8]  = 'Age (3) (3)';
cAge[9]  = 'Age (4) (1)';
cAge[10] = 'Age (4) (2)';
cAge[11] = 'Age (4) (3)';
```

I can do it with a `for` loop without problems:

```js
var cAge = [];

for (var i=1; i<=4; i++) {
  for (var j=1; j<=3; j++) {
    cAge.push('Age (' + i + ')' + ' ' + '(' + j + ')');
  }
}
```

However I am not able to show all of them using the following nested loop:

```js
for (var i=1; i<=4; i++) {
  for (var j=1; j<=3; j++) {
    console.log(cAge[j-1]); // <- What should j-1 be?
  }
}
```

It produces:

```js
Age (1) (1)
Age (1) (2)
Age (1) (3)
Age (1) (1)
Age (1) (2)
Age (1) (3)
Age (1) (1)
Age (1) (2)
Age (1) (3)
Age (1) (1)
Age (1) (2)
Age (1) (3)
```

What should `j-1` be?

Comment: You are pushing data in the `1-d` array. So just use `forEach` or `for-loop`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Accessing elements from a 1-D array using nested loops:

```js
const cAge = [],
  nrows = 4,
  ncols = 3;

for (var i = 1; i <= nrows; i++) {
  for (var j = 1; j <= ncols; j++) {
    cAge.push("Age (" + i + ")" + " " + "(" + j + ")");
  }
}

for (var i = 0; i < nrows; i++) {
  for (var j = 0; j < ncols; j++) {
    console.log(cAge[i * ncols + j]);
  }
}
```

Here, `ncols = 3`

| `i` in nested loop | `j` in nested loop | 1-D index |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 0 | `0 * 3 + 0` = 0 |
| 0 | 1 | `0 * 3 + 1` = 1 |
| 0 | 2 | `0 * 3 + 2` = 2 |
| 1 | 0 | `1 * 3 + 0` = 3 |
| 1 | 1 | `1 * 3 + 1` = 4 |
| 1 | 2 | `1 * 3 + 2` = 5 |
| 2 | 0 | `2 * 3 + 0` = 6 |
| 2 | 1 | `2 * 3 + 1` = 7 |
| 2 | 2 | `2 * 3 + 2` = 8 |

Comment: @manooooh Please check if this solves your problem, let me know if you have any issues.